# User behaviors tracking on Rooted Android devices

Tags: java, android, root, su

Iam researching about a solution which targeting only the rooted android devices to collect user behaviors data like search history, browsing history & most used applications. 
According to my understanding there is no open APIs or frameworks available to archive this. But since I'm targeting rooted devices, I know it is possible and already there are lot of applications which do such things.

Can any one give me a break through or suggestions how this could be archived. I'm not expecting the code work, But an overview about how this can be archived? or methodologies behind this process?